# How to call twitter API function within HTML and display results?

Tags: javascript, html, rest, twitter

I have a working function that, when used in the app.js file, will successfully open a twitter stream and display the content below(if console.log is used instead of print). However, when I take the function and put it in a script inside index.html, I get the error **"referenceError: require not defined"** I also get a GET error with the other scripts..perhaps I am referencing them incorrectly, but I've tried including them with only one .

I am trying to learn all this on my own. I have made a simply static website in the past, but only using html, css, and some basic jquery. I want to be able to stylize the text output by the function with css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Streaming</title>
<script src="..Twitter/config.js"></script>
<script src="..Twitter/package.json"></script>
<script src="..Twitter/app.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">


function displayStream() {
    var Twit = require('twit');
    var T = new Twit(config); 
    var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: 'Bernie Sanders' });
    var count = 0;
    var totalSentiment = 0;

      stream.on('tweet', function (tweet) {
      //Exclude retweets
        if(tweet.text.startsWith("RT") === false) {

          print(tweet.text)
          print("Sentiment score: " + sentiment(tweet.text).score)
          count += 1;
          totalSentiment += sentiment(tweet.text).score;
          print(count + " tweets analyzed");
          print("Aggregate Sentiment: " + totalSentiment);
          print("Average Sentiment:" + (totalSentiment/count).toFixed(2) + "\n");
};

});

};
```

```
 </head>
 <body onload="displayStream();">

     <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>


<p>displayStream()</p>
```

Comment: `..Twitter/config.js` is not a valid path, should most probably be `../Twitter/config.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Using Ajax script you can request URL and get response in following way

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'url',
})
.done(function(data) {
 document.getElementById("#myResponse").innerHTML=data;
})
.fail(function() {
  alert("Ajax failed to fetch data")
})
```

> Using plain Jquery you can achieve same result by following way using Jquery load function

```
$( "#div").load( "url", function( response, status, xhr ) {
console.log(response.ok);
document.getElementById("#myResponse").innerHTML=response;
if ( status == "error" ) {
}
});
```

> Using pure javascript you can achieve using XMLHttpRequest

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
alert(xhr.responseText);
}
}
xhr.open('GET', 'url', true);
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: I would like to, but for this project I am not supposed to use jQuery..just plain javascript

Comment: `Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. - [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/12011143)

Comment: Where would I need to insert the code in mine? Im not sure how to integrate them.

Answer (score 1):

For just javascipt you can use [fetchApi](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). It's will provide same feel as AJAX does.

For example :

```
fetch('ApiToFetchTweets', {
        method: 'get'
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('response here: ',response);


        }).then(function(json) {
        //console.log('parsed json', json);
        }).catch(function(ex) {
        //console.log('parsing failed', ex);
        })
```

Thanks,

Dinesh

Comment: Could you put that in context with my code? I am not sure how to integrate your code with mine.

Comment: Please confirm me that which server side language you are using to get twitter feeds ? So i can update my answer as per your requirement.

Comment: NodeJs and express with the twit package